# AngularJS ui-router tutorial undefined binding es2015

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm trying to build an es2015, offline, bundled (using webpack) version of the ui-router angular1 tutorial, but I'm getting caught up in trying to resolve some data passed to a component. Although the service function returns a resolved promise with the actual data, it never gets injected into the component. When I try to make a controller to examine it being passed in, if I pass in the name of the property being resolve, I get the error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: peopleProvider <- people
```

Here's some source. If you need to see more I can add you to the repo

app.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-aria';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'material-design-lite';

import 'material-design-lite/dist/material.css';
import './scss/main.scss';

import Layout from './components/layout/layout.component';
import PeopleService from './services/people.service';
import states from './config/app.states';

angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  Layout.name
])
.config(states)
.service('peopleService', PeopleService);
```

Simplified app.states.js

```
export default function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  
  $stateProvider
  // other states
  .state('lists', {
    url: '/lists',
    template: '<lists></lists>',
    resolve: {
      people: ['peopleService', PeopleService => {
        console.log(PeopleService.getAllPeople();
        return PeopleService.getAllPeople();
      }]
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

layout.component.js

```
import Lists from '../lists/lists.component';

export default angular.module('layout', [
  Lists.name
])
.component('layout', {
  templateUrl: './components/layout/layout.template.html'
});
```

list.component.js

```
export default angular.module('app.lists', [])
.component('lists', {
  templateUrl: './components/lists/lists.template.html',
  bindings: {
    people: '<' // from 'resolve' property of config/app.states
  },
  controller: class ListCtrl {
    constructor(people) {
      console.log(arguments);
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
});
```

PeopleService.getAllPeople() returns properly. The `people` property appears on the component, but it's always undefined, unless I use the above code where I try to pass `people` as an argument, in which case it throws the `$injector:unpr` error.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous answer was incorrect. I think to get closer to solution you need at least add `people` attribute to your `template` in `app.states.js`. Like this `<lists people="people"></lists>`

Comment: I ended up upgrading to ui-router v1.0.0 and used the 'component' property instead, got it working now